# Lock steps (prevent refit) in scikit-learn pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn

Is there a convenient mechanism for locking steps in a scikit-learn pipeline to prevent them from refitting on pipeline.fit()? For example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups

data = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
firsttwoclasses = data.target<=1
y = data.target[firsttwoclasses]
X = np.array(data.data)[firsttwoclasses]

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("vectorizer", CountVectorizer()),
    ("estimator", LinearSVC())
])

# fit intial step on subset of data, perhaps an entirely different subset
# this particular example would not be very useful in practice
pipeline.named_steps["vectorizer"].fit(X[:400])
X2 = pipeline.named_steps["vectorizer"].transform(X)

# fit estimator on all data without refitting vectorizer
pipeline.named_steps["estimator"].fit(X2, y)
print(len(pipeline.named_steps["vectorizer"].vocabulary_))

# fitting entire pipeline refits vectorizer
# is there a convenient way to lock the vectorizer without doing the above?
pipeline.fit(X, y)
print(len(pipeline.named_steps["vectorizer"].vocabulary_))
```

The only way I could think of doing this without intermediate transformations would be to define a custom estimator class (as seen [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html)) whose fit method does nothing and whose transform method is the transform of the pre-fit transformer. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the code, there doesn't seem to be anything in a Pipeline object with functionality like this: calling .fit() on the pipeline results in .fit() on each stage.

The best quick-and-dirty solution I could come up with is to monkey-patch away the stage's fitting functionality:

```py
pipeline.named_steps["vectorizer"].fit(X[:400])
# disable .fit() on the vectorizer step
pipeline.named_steps["vectorizer"].fit = lambda self, X, y=None: self
pipeline.named_steps["vectorizer"].fit_transform = model.named_steps["vectorizer"].transform

pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: It's unfortunate, but when you attach a lambda function like that to an instance, it doesn't get passed "self" the way it would if it was a native method. So, that part won't work the way you expect.

Comment: What would the model object be in this case?

Comment: This solution is very close to a working one! You'd just have to change `pipeline.named_steps["vectorizer"].fit = lambda self, X, y=None: self` for `pipeline.named_steps["vectorizer"].__class__.fit = lambda s, X, y=None: s`

Answer (score 1):

There is still no convenient way. The feature has been discussed previously but the [issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/8370) is still open.

However, the following freezes sklearn estimators and adds an `unfreeze()` method to later revert the changes. It does so by assigning a new class to the object, which has the original class as the base class but overrides the relevant methods. Using `obj.unfreeze()` reverts everything to normal.

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from copy import deepcopy

def freeze_estimator(obj: BaseEstimator, in_place=True) -> BaseEstimator:        
   
    class Frozen(obj.__class__):                                    
        def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):                            
            return self
        def fit_transform(self, X, y, **kwargs):                                        
            return self.transform(X, **kwargs)                                    
        def unfreeze(self, original_class=obj.__class__):
            self.__class__ = original_class
            return self
    
    if not in_place:
        obj = deepcopy(obj)
    
    name = 'Frozen' + obj.__class__.__name__                         
    Frozen.__name__ = name
    Frozen.__qualname__ = name
    obj.__class__ = Frozen
    
    return obj
```

**Note:** Using a prefit frozen estimator does not play well with `sklearn.base.clone()` as it reverts the estimator to unfit state. Hence we cannot use this code — at least out of the box — with many sklearn tools like `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate()` because they use `clone()` internally. The only remotely convenient workaround I found is to replace `clone` with deepcopy at runtime:

```py
from copy import deepcopy 
import sklearn.model_selection
sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.__globals__[clone] = deepcopy
# ... cv on pipeline with frozen transformers here...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a subset of your pipeline like

> preprocess_pipeline = Pipeline(pipeline.best_estimator_.steps[:-1]) #
>   exclude the last step

and then

> tmp = preprocess_pipeline.fit(x_train) normalized_x =
>   tmp.fit_transform(x_train)